# I need help to make my jQuery menu behave

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm learning jQuery. I've made a menu system from a tutorial I found.

This is the code.

```js
$(function() {
    $('div.tab-panel ul.tabs li').on('click', function() { // Clicks on any tab
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        var $panel = $('#'+$(this).attr('rel'));
        if($panel.hasClass('active')){
            $panel.slideUp(500,function(){
                $panel.removeClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('not active');
            if($panel.siblings('.active').length > 0){
                $panel.siblings('.active').slideUp(500,function(){
                    $panel.siblings('.active').removeClass('active',show_panel());
                });
            } else {
                show_panel();
            }
            function show_panel(){
                $panel.slideDown(500,function(){
                    $panel.addClass('active');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background  : #fafafa;
    font-family : Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color       : #333333;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs {
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs li {
    list-style-type : none;
    display         : inline-block;
    background      : #999999;
    margin          : 0;
    padding         : 3px 10px;
    border-radius   : 4px 4px 0 0;
    color           : #ffffff;
    font-weight     : 200;
    cursor          : pointer;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs li:hover {
    color      : #ffffff;
    background : #666666;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs li.active {
    color      : #ffffff;
    background : #666666;
}
div.tab-panel div.panel {
    display       : none;
    background    : #c9c9c9;
    padding       : 30px;
    border-radius : 0 0 4px 4px;
}
div.tab-panel div.panel.active {
    display : block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>tab-panel</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab-panel">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li rel="panel_1">panel 1</li>
            <li rel="panel_2">panel 2</li>
            <li rel="panel_3">panel 3</li>
            <li rel="panel_4">panel 4</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div id="panel_1" class="panel">
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel_2" class="panel">
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel_3" class="panel">
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel_4" class="panel">
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a repl of it working: https://tab-panel--computinginschools.repl.co/

The problem is that if you click quickly on one tab and then another, both panels open. How can I prevent this?

Comment: use a debounce on the logic inside the click handler, root of the issue though is siblings classes are still there due to delay before removing

Comment: Yes, that's what I discovered - ideally I want to prevent the click event firing on the tabs until the animation and removal of 'active' class is complete.

Comment: yep as said use a debounce, if its set to >=500 ms then no matter how many times the user clicks its only going to fire the event once every 500ms which is enough time for the  callbacks to complete

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone - sorry to be thick but how do I implement this here? I've found this but not sure how to include it in my code. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Comment: I'm not sure this will work (unless I'm debouncing the wrong thing). Debouncing the click function will wait for 500ms before showing the menu panel. I want to show the menu panel immediately and then wait for 500 ms before detecting another click. What do I debounce??

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li#panel_1').click(function() { 
      $('.content1').toggle("fast");
        $('.content2').hide();
         $('.content3').hide();
           $('.content4').hide();
    });
    
     $('li#panel_2').click(function() { 
      $('.content2').toggle("fast");
       $('.content1').hide();
         $('.content3').hide();
           $('.content4').hide();
     });

     $('li#panel_3').click(function() { 
      $('.content3').toggle("fast");
        $('.content2').hide();
         $('.content1').hide();
           $('.content4').hide();
    });
    
     $('li#panel_4').click(function() { 
      $('.content4').toggle("fast");
       $('.content2').hide();
         $('.content3').hide();
           $('.content1').hide();
    
    });
       
      
});
```

```css
body {
    background  : #fafafa;
    font-family : Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color       : #333333;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs {
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs li {
    list-style-type : none;
    display         : inline-block;
    background      : #999999;
    margin          : 0;
    padding         : 3px 10px;
    border-radius   : 4px 4px 0 0;
    color           : #ffffff;
    font-weight     : 200;
    cursor          : pointer;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs li:hover {
    color      : #ffffff;
    background : #666666;
}
div.tab-panel ul.tabs li.active {
    color      : #ffffff;
    background : #666666;
}
div.tab-panel div.panel {
    display       : none;
    background    : #c9c9c9;
    padding       : 30px;
    border-radius : 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.content1 .conten2 .content3 .content4 {
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <div class="tab-panel">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li id="panel_1">panel 1</li>
            <li id="panel_2">panel 2</li>
            <li id="panel_3" >panel 3</li>
            <li id="panel_4" >panel 4</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
               <div class="content1 panel">
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
                content 1<br/>
               </div>
               <div class="content2 panel">
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                content 2<br/>
                </div>
              <div class="content3 panel">
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
                content 3<br/>
            </div>
               <div class="content4 panel">
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>
                content 4<br/>

            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem is still there if you spam the menu fast enough

Comment: You can change it to show to make it fast enough for you to see. I set the .slideToggle("fast") for you look at the above code again

Comment: Thanks for the code. It does seem better - however one of the features of the original code that I posted is that you can click on the same tab again to close the panel. This is no longer the case with your new code.

Comment: I edited it for you to toggle. so it close if you close it anywhere. Try the new code. That should work for you now.

Comment: Thank you @Crystal - that works well. I think I over complicated my original attempt?!

Comment: cool glad I can help.